# How can I get IntelliJ to open my zsh terminal as the default with the starting directory?

Tags: intellij-idea, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've downloaded Ubuntu 2204.1.6 with WSL so that I can use the zsh terminal and its git prompt in IntelliJ. My `.bashrc` is configured to open `zsh` so I set the shell path to Ubuntu. Although the zsh terminal is able to open in IntelliJ, it doesn't change to the starting directory upon creating a new terminal.

[image]

Instead, it starts at the default home directory instead of the `Start Directory` set in the above photo.

[image]

How can I change this behaviour so that it opens with the `start directory`?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Will it help if you close and reopen terminal?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition). Closing and reopening doesn't help

Comment: Is it possible to check the issue with 2022.2 version?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I'm putting the solution here to help others.

In the `Shell Path` you just need to put `ubuntu run` and it should work.